# Textwrangler follows current space on mac

Tags: mac, osx-spaces, textwrangler

My textwrangler will follow me wherever I am, whichever space I'm active in.

Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least since OS X 10.7, the option to control this is in the *Dock item* of the application, in this case Text Wrangler.

Right-click its Dock icon, select *Options » Assign To » None* (or *This Desktop*).

[image: Screenshot of Dock item menu]

Comment: OMG, i can't believe that _this_ is what I've been doing wrong. god I'm stupid :P

thanks for the help, man!